# AT&T UNIX System V Release 4 - How do I create a new "Administrator" user?

Tags: group, administration, useradd

I am running AT&T UNIX System V Release 4 Version 2.1 inside VirtualBox, and want to create a new "user account" for myself.  At first, I simply created a new user with the `useradd` command, but didn't specify a group.  When I logged in, I didn't even have a high enough permission level to create a new directory in my home folder.  I then deleted my account and recreated it using the same command, except that I specified that the group is "adm".  After doing this, I was able to create a new directory.  This indicates to me that I now have a higher permission level.

**Is this the correct way to add an administrator user?  If so, what limitations are still in place?**

Comment: If you have the command `sudo usermod` you can use that to modify a user.

Comment: The `sudo` command isn't available on the system.

Comment: @Strato1 - what about the command `usermod`?

Comment: @slm  I have tried the `usermod` command, but am unsure how to use it to add administrative privileges.

Comment: @illuminÉ  I know that this is not a problem involving installed packages.  Also, my system cannot run the command you provided.  On my system, it is used such as: `pkgadd -d diskette1`.  It installs packages off of floppy disks.

Comment: @Strato1 - `usermod -G adm <user>` would be how you'd add the `adm` group to user `<user>`.

Comment: @slm Thank you.  So, specifying the "adm" usergroup is the correct way to do it?  If so, I have already done it.  Also, is anyone able to explain what an administrator user still is/isn't able to do, compared to the root user and a regular user?

Comment: @slm The `usermod -G adm <user>` command returns the following error: `UX: usermod: ERROR: adm is the primary group name. Choose another.`       Note that I am doing this as root user, and it does work to specify the "adm" group when creating a new user (not when modifying).

Comment: The administrative user role depends on the distro. Are you using Unixware? Open Desktop?

Comment: @Strato1 - you already added that group, I was explaining how to do this from scratch with a new account when setting it up 8-)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The system has absolutely no GUI.  It isn't Unixware or Open Desktop.  If you want to try the system yourself, it can be found on winworldpc.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ATT SVR4 — it was old before my time. But from your description, I think I can provide enough guidance to solve your problem.

Unix doesn't exactly have a notion of “administrator user”. That's a Windows name that doesn't map directly to a Unix concept. Under Unix, the only administrator account is root, user ID 0. Accounts that belong to physical users don't have such characteristics. An administrator is someone who knows the password to the root account. On systems that use [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo), such as Ubuntu, you can say that an administrator account is an account that is allowed to run programs as root through `sudo`, but sudo is not a historical Unix tool and is not bundled with SVR4. The traditional way to become root is with the [`su`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29) command, and that requires knowing the root password.

Accounts do belong to one or more groups, which can indirectly confer privileges, but that's more varied than having “administrator users”. I remember systems where the `adm` group gives the permission to read system log files (it's even the case in some recent Linux distributions); but that's only one thing among many. In some Unix variants (I don't know about SVR4), running `su` has an additional prerequisite, that the user must belong to the [`wheel` group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29#Wheel_group).

In any case, you don't need any special permission to create a subdirectory in your home directory. It's possible that the `adduser` command on SVR4 doesn't create the new user's home directory, or requires an option to do so; the syntax of `useradd` is not standardized, so check the man page on your system.

In summary:

- To create an account, use `useradd`. If you need to create the user's home directory by hand, you can use these commands (as root of course):

  ```
  mkdir /home/bob
  chown bob /home/bob
  chgrp users /home/bob      # or whatever bob's primary group is        
  chmod 755 /home/bob
  ```
- To create an administrator user, create a user, and give the person who'll be using the account the root password. If required, add the user to the `wheel` group (either with built-in tools, if provided on your Unix variant, or by editing the `/etc/group` file manually).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  However, adding a user to the `adm` group does allow the user to use certain commands which weren't available before.  Also, I was unable to create a directory in my own home directory before I specified the `adm` group.  The `wheel` group does not exist on SVR4.  I did not know about the `su` command, though.  Thanks.

Comment: One quick question: What does `chmod 755 /home/bob` do?

Comment: @Strato1 Every user should be able to create a directory in their home directory. If you couldn't, it's probably because you were in the wrong directory or the home directory had wrong permission. If you need further help with that, copy-paste a transcript of the commands that you used, the messages produced by these commands, and the entries in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. The `chmod` command sets reasonable permissions (readable by everyone, writable only by the owner) to the newly created home directory.

Comment: I think I realize what I did wrong.  When I created the new user, I failed to specify the `-m` switch.  Because of this, I had to create the new directory using the `mkdir` command.  I must not have set the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

On old unix when you create a user,you must tell to create
home.
So correct way is

```
useradd -g other -m -d /home/utente
passwd utente
chown utente /home/utente
chgrp utente /home/utente
chmod 755 /home/utente
```

of course replace utente with your name.
If you want admin user,must use root as group
,but is dangerous,better use normal user and use

```
su -
```

for admin templates.
And if you want you can create a script for automatic creation of user.
How to do?
Simply google for it ;)